# How to create an internal comment on a jira issue using the JIRA Cloud REST API

Tags: json, groovy, jira, jira-rest-api

It's really hard to find a clear answer about how to create a comment on an issue which is internal only.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The JIRA Cloud REST API Documentation specifies the following schema for setting properties on comments when creating or updating a comment on an incident

[https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/cloud/#api/2/issue/{issueIdOrKey}/comment-addComment](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/cloud/#api/2/issue/%7BissueIdOrKey%7D/comment-addComment)

```
"properties": {
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
        "title": "Entity Property",
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "key": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "value": {}
        },
        "additionalProperties": false
    }
}
```

To make a comment on an issue internal (meaning only service desk agents can see the comment) you need to set the `sd.public.comment` key to have the value `{ "internal": true }`
Which can be achieved by passing the following JSON in the body of the create or update API request.

```
{
    "properties": {
        "key": "sd.public.comment",
        "value": {
            "internal": true
        }
    }
}
```

You will also need to set the Content-Type header on the request.

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

The following is an example of a creating an internal comment using a Groovy script - the scripting language used by ScriptRunner (a popular JIRA plugin)

```
post("/rest/api/2/issue/${issue.id}/comment")
    .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
    .body([
        body: "This is the text which will appear in the comment",
        properties: [
            [key: "sd.public.comment", value: [ "internal": true ]]
        ]
    ]).asString()
```

Note that Object / JSON mapping will differ depending on which scripting language or HTTP Request framework you are using.

Comment: The _properties_ property is read-only in the .NET SDK. Does anyone know how to work around that?