# Jira Add Internal Comment JSON syntax

Tags: json, jira

I am trying to add an internal comment to an existing Jira ticket. I am able to add a comment, but it is not internal. I looked at this url [How to create an internal comment on a jira issue using the JIRA Cloud REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45031475/how-to-create-an-internal-comment-on-a-jira-issue-using-the-jira-cloud-rest-api), but I cant see from this the proper syntax.

Here is what I have at the moment, and although the JSON syntax is correct, I suspect it is not the right format for Jira.

```
   "body":{
      "type":"doc",
      "version":1,
      "content":[
         {
            "type":"paragraph",
            "content":[
               {
                  "text":"This text was added using thwe rest-api. test kb1",
                  "type":"text"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   "properties":{
      "key":"sd.public.comment",
      "value":{
         "internal":true
      }
   }
}
```

I have tried various different formats and search on the Jira KB, but I just cant see what the proper format is.
Can you please help?